# Mix-blend-mode ignored after zoom [Safari]

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari, mix-blend-mode

## Setup & Goal

I am trying to apply a texture to all the content on my page. The aim is to make the site look like a piece of printed paper.

In order to achieve that, I am using an `absolute`ly positioned `div` with the same dimensions as my content. It has an image as background and user-interaction is disabled. I use the `mix-blend-mode: multiply` to apply the texture to everything behind.

The set up looks something like this; however I was unable to reproduce the issue in the snippet editor:

```css
.main-content {
position:relative;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-color:lightblue;
border: solid 10px red;

}

.texture {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: -10px;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  Lorem Ipsum
  <div class="texture"></div>
</div>
```

## Issues

This works fine on initial load in all browsers where `mix-blend-mode` is enabled. https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_mix-blend-mode

Issues arise however in:

- Safari (OSX)
- Safari (iOS)

Whenever the zoom functionality of the browser is used, either through pinch or automatically through activation of an input field, the Browser seems to "forget" that the `mix-blend-mode` property is set on the element and shows it fully opaque in front of all content.

Zooming back out does not solve the issue.

Disabling and re-enabling the `mix-blend-mode` property  manually through the developer tools **does** solve the issue.

Is this a known bug in Safari? Are there any known workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Still seeing this in iOS 17.2

Comment: Unfortunately no updates. I eventually gave up and solved it differently.

Comment: Also still seeing this issue, would love to find a fix